# Tensors, connection between vectors and multilinear maps.

Tags: tensor-products

Let $V$ be a real $n$-dimensional vector space. On the one hand, I am going to consider $T_{r , s}(V)$ as the set of multilinear maps
$$
\underbrace{V \times \cdots \times V}_{r\text{ copies}} \times \underbrace{V^* \times \cdots \times V^*}_{s \text{ copies}} \to \mathbb{R}.
$$
On the other hand, I consider the tensor product vector space $V \otimes W$ as wikipedia defines (it can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product), where $W$ is other real $m$-dimensional vector space . And tensor product of $v \in V$ and $w \in W$, $v \otimes w$, belongs to $V \otimes W$.

I consider the set of $(r , s)$-type tensors $V_{r , s}$, expanding this last definition:
$$V_{r , s} := \underbrace{V \otimes \cdots \otimes V}_{r\text{ copies}} \otimes \underbrace{V^* \otimes \cdots \otimes V^*}_{s \text{ copies}}.$$
Furthermore, $T_{r , s}(V)$ and $V_{r , s}$ are $k$-dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$, where $k = r^n s^n$, and it can be shown that these two vector spaces are isomorphic.

If I take two different $u \in V_{r , s}$ and $v \in V_{r' , s'}$, the tensor product of these two vectors belongs to $V_{r + r' , s + s'}$ and is given by
$$
u \otimes v = u_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes u_r \otimes v_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes v_{r'} \otimes u_1^* \otimes \ldots \otimes u_s^* \otimes v_1^* \otimes \ldots \otimes v_{s'}^*
$$
if
$$
u = u_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes u_r \otimes u_1^* \otimes \ldots \otimes u_s^* \quad \mbox{ and } \quad v = v_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes v_{r'} \otimes v_1^* \otimes \ldots \otimes v_{s'}^*\mbox{.}
$$
Since $T_{r , s}(V)$ and $T_{r' , s'}(V)$ are two vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$, their tensor product, $T_{r , s}(V) \otimes T_{r' , s'}(V)$ makes sense, and $f \otimes g \in T_{r , s}(V) \otimes T_{r' , s'}(V)$ for each $f \in T_{r , s}(V)$ and $g \in T_{r' , s'}(W)$. I found that $f \otimes g$ can be defined as a map in $T_{r + r' , s + s'}(V)$, and given by $f \otimes g (u , v) = f(u) g(v)$ (for instance here: https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/165069). Can I deduce this last statement using the first?